# Vagrant network is not active error

Tags: vagrant, libvirt

I am trying to create a kvm machine with ubuntu using vagrant. I already installed the plugin, got the box file, and set up the project and vagrant file. When I run `vagrant up` I get this error:

> /home//.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-kvm-0.1.9/lib/vagrant-kvm/driver/driver.rb:525:in `create': Call to virDomainCreateWithFlags failed: internal error: Network 'vagrant' is not active. (Libvirt::Error)

After googling for around an hour, I am no closer to figuring out how to fix the problem. Does anyone know what is causing the error and how to fix it?